# DownloadData method failed with unknown error, but only on some PC

Tags: c#, google-translate, webclient

I would like to ask for advice.
I have a method where I send translate.google a string of text to be translated. The method is called through the BackgroundWorker. The problem is that on some computers it works without problems, but on some computers fail me DownloadData. An exception only reports an unknown error. I'm sorry for my English. Thanks for any advice.

```
    private string translateCleanString(string cleanText)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding enc = new UnicodeEncoding();

        string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?text={0}&langpair={1}", cleanText, "sk|cs");
        byte[] data = null;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
        {
            client.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.Default;
            client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100824 Firefox/3.6.9";
            client.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us,en;q=0.5";
            client.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";

            try
            {
                data = client.DownloadData(url);   //Fail, row 300
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            return FiltracePrelozenehoTextuOdBordelu(Encoding.GetEncoding(Regex.Match(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"], "(?<=charset=)[\\w-]+").Value).GetString(data));
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Exceptions

**e.StackTrace**

- v System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
- v System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
- v System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address)
- v Prekladac_titulku.Preklad.translateCleanString(String cleanText) v C:\Users\radicz\Desktop\Prekladac_titulku (verze 2)\Prekladac_titulku (verze 2)\Prekladac_titulku\Preklad.cs:řádek 300

**e.InnerException**

- Unable to read data from the transmission connection: Connection closed ..

**e.Message**

- During the WebClient request threw an exception.

**WebException e**

- Response: NULL
- Status: UnknownError
- Source: System
- InternalStatus: RequestFatal

Comment: please also post the relevant exception (e.Message, e.StackTrace, ..)

Answer (score 0):

Try catching a `WebException` instead and see if it provides more detail.

```
 try
 {
      data = client.DownloadData(url);   
 }
 catch(WebException e)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(e.Status.ToString());
 }
```